# printing on nasm 64bit Linux machine

Tags: 64-bit, nasm

I'm trying to print out a float value without using printf

any ideas?

I know with printf I have to use xmm0 registers to pass the values through, but for integers i use general purpose registers....

ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: i'm working on inputting float values into an array, in assembly language, then outputting them it,

Comment: Okay, so what's your question? This works a lot better if you ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: question: How do I output a float value off of my array, while not using printf? any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

How about sprintf or snprintf?  They output to a string.

Comment: dont really know how that would work, did some research on it, but it seems as if it would be a lot more work to try to convert from string to float and vice versa